# How to force enlarge a picture

Tags: php, html

Lets say there is a picture that has width:300 and height:400...

Is there anyway to force these pictures to enlarge at size of width:500 and height:500 in html or in php?

```
<img src="<?php echo "/uploads/store/logo/".$store['logo'];?>" width="460" height="590" alt="" class="front-image"> 
                  <img src="<?php echo "/uploads/store/logo/".$store['logo'];?>" width="460" height="590" alt="" class="back-image">
```

What I tried to do it this

```
<div style="width:460px; height: 590px;">
                    <a href="#"> 
                  <img src="<?php echo "/uploads/store/logo/".$store['logo'];?>" width="460" height="590" alt="" class="front-image"> 
                  <img src="<?php echo "/uploads/store/logo/".$store['logo'];?>" width="460" height="590" alt="" class="back-image"> 
                  <span class="single-pro-quick-view"> <span class="single-pro-quick-table"> <span class="single-pro-quick-table-cell"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </span> </span> </span> 
                  </a>
                  </div>
```

Comment: When displaying the image, set the `height` and `width` of the `img` element?

Comment: I did but my container keeps on iterating at different sizes.

Comment: Show us your code, and we might be able to spot potential errors.

Comment: (1) It's not clear at all what you mean by that.  (2) We can't tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't show it to us and explain the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Also you should try to do that with CSS. Something like: `image-selector{ width: 500px; height: 500px; }`

Comment: Check my update code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply set the height and width inside the tag, or use css

example:

```
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" width="500px" height="500px">
```